# How to use 2 methods of filling NA in 1 column in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, na

I have a data frame with 1 column. 
- There are many NA values at the beginning and at the end that I would like to eliminate them completely.
- At the same time, there are some NA values in the between of 2 available values that I would like to fill them by the mean of 2 closed available values.
For illustration, I attach the image here for your imagine.
I can not think of any solution. Just wonder if anyone can please help me with that.

Thank you for your help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzCML.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,i have reproduced example by using random numbers

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

random_index = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 1))
random_range = np.arange(10,15)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 1)), columns=list('A'))
df.loc[10:15,'A'] = "#N/A"
for c in random_index:
    df.loc[c,"A"] = "#N/A"

// replacing start from here

df[df=="#N/A"]= np.nan
index  = list(np.where(df['A'].isna()))[0]
drops = []
for i in index:
    if pd.isnull(df.loc[(i-1),"A"]) is False  and pd.isnull(df.loc[(i+1),"A"]) is False:
        df.loc[i,"A"] =  (df.loc[(i-1),"A"]+df.loc[(i+1),"A"])/2
    else:
        drops.append(i)

df = df.drop(df.index[drops]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, if each N/A is in string format, replace either with `np.nan`.The most straightforward possible way is to use `isnan` on the given column, then extract true indices(such as using the result on a `np.arange` array). From there you can either use a for to iterate indices to check if they are sequential or not, or calculate the distance between consecutive elements to find the ones not equal to 1.